# Tor, i2p good extensions for browser, improve usage

Tags: firefox, security, proxy, skype, privacy

I need some information about TOR / i2p. The thing is: my use is totally for privacy. For freedom. And I know that some stuff can deanonymize the user of the onion network, such as Flash or Java applets, but one of the main reasons I want to use Tor and why I do use the service is because I don't agree with ISP's surveillance, that we know is done to be used only (probably) for (illegal) profit and/or disclosure to governments as well (it can be for profit in this way too, of course)... one other is the fact that a lot of websites don't use https (we know NSA has been able to unencrypt https and they probably are able to do so still I guess... if you don't know about it yet just search online), that even being not that secure is something already so your information, your searches and all are not going to be totally easy to read and maybe only very powerful organizations and people, or with good knowledge on the subject are going to have some possibility to uncover your communication if the best technology is in use and has been correctly implemented and also is being correctly used on a day-to-day basis.

Then what I want of information if you can provide me as a favour: how to improve Tor's possibilities of being anonymous? Let's say for example: I am a user of a *nix based system (not an expert at the moment though).
Because, is it really safe to just close the Tor Browser Bundle and reopen it? Is all the possible tracking data going to be gone by then? I know for example that the https everywhere extension is a good service, I guess we 
can trust enough on it, though I don't believe in using the observatory feature as we know that smart analysis of traffic info may be able to deanonymize a user (and who knows if someone (malicious) is going to be able to get their dirty hands on the data?), so I don't enable it and hope they comply and don't collect any data without consent, what I don't believe they do, this is something M$ does, not people that with a good heart creates this kind of services that are real benefits to humanity to fight the oppression we live under this days (because ISP's surveillance (and other kinds, even like M$'s (that comply with governments surveillances for what we know) and all this kind of stuff is at least a kind of totalitarianism (disguised or not) oh it is!).

So to sum up: I can even use Facebook onion service and all, just so my ISP don’t see when I use the service for example. I can even use Skype service if I want, I don’t need to hide totally, I just want my rights as much as possible, so:

1. Do you know any other trustworthy extensions I can use to improve the platform usage?
2. Do you believe that i2p is better in some way? For example: do you know if the possible leakages that can happen with the use of Flash for example can also occur with the use of i2p? Even using ipredia?

I would use for example Skype wrapped by a service like i2p or Tor, but wouldn’t that draw attention to me personally as a target for these malicious stupid people that think they are something more than puppets?

Well, that’s all general information that I ask you if you can provide me with.

Comment: Edward Snowden’s three tips for digital privacy: 1. Encrypt your hard drive. 2. Use browser plug-ins to avoid being tracked online, for example Ghostery. You can also choose sites, such as the search engine DuckDuckGo, which do not record or share your searches. 3. Cover your tracks with Tor.

Comment: I also suggest that you edit your question and remove any overt requests for software recommendations as they should be properly asked about at [Software Recommendations Q&A](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi @karel ! Thanks a lot for your commentsand all ! I do encrypt my hard drive and use plugins and try to use tor as much as possible... I wasn't aware of where I should go to ask for information (as Software Recommendations Q&A session for example). I just saw the button "Ask Question" and did so... sorry... Can I leave it in this way this time? Next opportunity, even if with a new nick to improve anonymity, I'll take a better look and read faq's and/or whatever helps me understand better how the platform should ideally be used... Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and maybe I should look more and better for it? But I am finding it more difficult (I know they're "smaller") to find any good and easier informations on i2p. Tor has a much wider knowledge base throughout the web... anyway... I'll keep looking and who knows if someone can answer my question about this point... Thanks again!